# how can I access the variables of my current component in angular without using "this"

Tags: angular

This question will sound a bit odd, but I will explain the reason. I am using d3.js combined with Angular. everything is fine, but sometimes there are events within the logic of d3.js in which "this" is a different value from the context of angular. For this reason I would like to know if there is a way to directly access the variables that I have defined in my component in the style of:

```
HomeComponent.myVar   //HomeComponent name of my current component
```

Instead of

```
this.myvar
```

this is a example of my problem using d3.js

```
Node.on("mouseout", unfocus);

function unfocus(){
 console.log(this); //problem context angular
}

Node.mouseover(function(d){
 console.log(this); //this is not context angular, is a value of this event
 console.log(HomeComponent.myvar); //not works, but is my idea
 })
```

thank you.

Comment: Try `Node.mouseover((d) => { ... })`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks, I put an example, but I just updated my real problem.

Comment: Try `unfocus = () => { console.log(this; }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I appreciate your help, but I am somewhat confused. I need to have the context of d3.js and the context of angular. in this way he would lose the context of d3.js

Comment: @ConnorsFan I would think that the best way to solve this problem is to be able to access the angular variables in some way without using the "this"

Answer (score 0):

The comments explain that you can use another syntax to still be able to access `this`:

```
Node.mouseover(d => {
    console.log(this);
})
```

If you really want to keep the other syntax, which I don't recommend, you can store `this` in another variable:

```
let self = this;

Node.mouseover(function(d){
    console.log(self);
})
```

I don't recommend it because it's harder to understand, it's error prone, and it's not always clear what the scope of the variable is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand your answer perfectly. but what I am not sure about is where and when to define "let self = this;"

Comment: " I don't recommend" why?

Answer (score 0):

try placing your variables outside of the class' scope with a var/let/const keyword. you could than try and access the variable without "this"